# blend effect : change color or appear only when overlaid

Tags: css, svg, graphics

I'm struggling with a graphic effect I'm trying to achieve and I could use some help. I working on a portfolio. There is a green logo button, which, when clicked, open a side menu on the left of the screen. I'm trying to make the green logo to gradually turn white while the side menu is sliding on it. It though about two solution:

1 - using mix-blend-mode : But I can't figure any value for this property which can render my logo like I want it. I need it white when rendered atop on something else, and all I get is grey.

2 - having a second white logo hidden, that only shows when slided on by the side menu. But I can't figure how to show an element only if it's overlaid by another.

Here is some graphic of what I want to achieve for a better understanding, whih the logo being the green ring at the bottom of the page. Have you any clue on how to achieve this effect ?

[image]

Here is also a basic code sandbox with my layout/configuration : https://codesandbox.io/s/logo-color-change-with-side-menu-3bj1m?file=/src/Logo/Logo.tsx

Comment: Please put up enough HTML and CSS for us to be able to see how you are sliding in the side menu.

Comment: I think I'd draw two annuluses one on top of the other and clip the top one with the overlay graphic.

Comment: AHaworth I will try to put some code sandbox tomorrow so it will more convenient.

@RobertLongson how would you proceed to clip the top one with the overlay graphic ?

Comment: There's no code for me to start from. Please add a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to the question.

Comment: @RobertLongson I edited my question with a link to a code sandbox. Is it ok ?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to include the logo twice, with different colors. While I am doing this here with a `<use>` element referencing a `<symbol>`, it would work the same if you instantiated the logo component twice. The main trick is in the CSS anyway: define the color used with `stroke: currentColor`. That gives you the opportunity to re-color the logo from outside the component. (or from its top level.)

It goes like this: At the bottom is the colored logo, then the menu, and on top is the "cutout" logo colored in the background color. It is clipped with `inset(0 0 0 50%)` to a rectangle that fits the extent of the menu. Then, for animation, you move both the menu position and the left inset of the clip path at once.

```css
#logo {
  fill: none;
  stroke: currentColor;
  stroke-width: 110.42px;
}
.menu {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0%;
  width: 0%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #007b6e;
  animation: show-menu 2s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
}
.logo {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0%;
  left: 0%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 25%;
}
.logo-main {
  color: #007b6e;
}
.logo-cutout {
  color: white;
  clip-path: inset(0 0 0 100%);
  animation: show-cutout 2s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
}
@keyframes show-menu {
  to { left: 40%; width: 60% }
}
@keyframes show-cutout {
  to { clip-path: inset(0 0 0 40%) }
}
```

```html
<svg width=0 height=0>
  <symbol id=logo viewBox="0 0 211 211">
    <g transform="matrix(0.37734,0,0,0.37734,-200.914,-264.742)">
      <circle cx="811.026" cy="980.18" r="223.368" />
    </g>
  </symbol>
</svg>
<svg class="logo logo-main"><use href="#logo" /></svg>
<div class="menu"></div>
<svg class="logo logo-cutout"><use href="#logo" /></svg>
```